# Magento CMS pages side nav - need to sort list

Tags: php, magento, sorting

I am using this code to create a dynamic lost of CMS pages in Magento, it;'s working fine but I'd love to sort it alphabetically and I cannot work out how to do it

```
    <?php
$cmsPages = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
            ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1)
            ->addFieldToFilter('identifier', array(
                array(
                    'nin' => array(
                            'home',
                            'no-route',
                            'enable-cookies',
                            'thank-you',
                            'home-demo',
                            'empty'
                        )
                    )
                )
            );

?>

<style type="text/css">
    #cms-navigation a.active { color: red; }​
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.pathname,
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");
    jQuery('#cms-navigation a').each(function(){
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
            jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
 });
 </script>

<div class="block">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span>CMS Navigation</span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ul id="cms-navigation" style="padding: 10px;">
            <?php    



            foreach($cmsPages as $_cms):
                    $page = $_cms->getData();
                    //sort ($_cms->getData('title'));

                ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() . $page['identifier']; ?>"><?php echo $_cms['title']; ?></a></li>
                <?php

                 endforeach;

                 ?>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see where I've commented out my attempt at sorting, I've tried just about everything I can think of but now I'm a bit stumped.

Many thanks to anyone who can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the setOrder() method inherited from the [Varien_Data_Collection_Db](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.1/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php) superclass

```
$cmsPages = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1)
        ->addFieldToFilter('identifier', array(
            array(
                'nin' => array(
                        'home',
                        'no-route',
                        'enable-cookies',
                        'thank-you',
                        'home-demo',
                        'empty'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
->setOrder('title','ASC');
```

Comment: Correctomundo! Many thanks for that. You saved me a few hours there.